# Error: Hotspot cannot not be embedded in sphere for lack of browser support (Marzipano)

Tags: javascript

I am using marzipano Tool and start getting an Error: Hotspot cannot not be embedded in sphere for lack of browser support.

Not able to understand Why? initially it wasn't coming

```
data.forEach(function(hotspot, index) {
                const yaw1 = hotspot.yaw * that.degrees2radians;
                const pitch1 = hotspot.pitch * that.degrees2radians;
                const element = that.createInfoHotspotElement(hotspot, index);

                // Get the hotspot container for scene.
                const container = that.scene.hotspotContainer();

                console.log(hotspot);

                element && container.createHotspot(element, {
                    yaw: yaw1,
                    pitch: pitch1
                }, {
                        perspective: {
                            radius: 1640
                        }
                    });
            });
```

When I remove perspective object it is working Fine.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for two days, I came to know the reason for this Error.

Actually, In the project in which I have been working on, because of wrong HTML and CSS schema, marzipano **DIV** element of ID(**marzipano_test_css3d_support**) during rendering was not able to get **height** which it is creating internally (below is the snippet)

```
84: [function(t, e, i) {
        "use strict";
        function r() {
            var t = s("perspective")
              , e = document.createElement("div")
              , i = "undefined" != typeof e.style[t];
            if (i && "WebkitPerspective" === t) {
                var r = "__marzipano_test_css3d_support__"
                  , n = document.createElement("style");
                n.textContent = "@media(-webkit-transform-3d){#" + r + "{height: 3px;})",
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(n),
                e.id = r,
                document.body.appendChild(e),
                i = e.offsetHeight > 0,
                n.parentNode.removeChild(n),
                e.parentNode.removeChild(e)
            }
            return i
        }
        function n() {
            return o !== undefined ? o : o = r()
        }
        var o, s = t("../util/dom").prefixProperty;
        e.exports = n
    }
```

Because of this i = e.offsetHeight > 0 was returning false.

We fixed some CSS property and now the tool is working fine.

Hope this will help